# Mosync Javascript NativeUI Editbox as Password field

Tags: javascript, c++, mosync

Now i am working in Mosync NativeUI with javascript.. I want to show characters in Editbox widget as "Password char(*****)like this"..

```
<div data-widgetType="EditBox" id="editbox"
data-width="100%" data-text="Edit me" data-fontSize="20">
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On InitUI

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",function(){
        mosync.nativeui.initUI();
        document.getNativeElementById("txtpassword").addEventListener("EditBoxEditingDidEnd", getPassword);
    },true);
```

Get Password and convert into "*****" when editbox losts focus...

```
function getPassword(editBox,text)
    {               

        var txtpwd=document.getNativeElementById("txtpassword");
        Inputvalidation("txtpassword",function(unamex)
                {
                        if(unamex!="")
                        {                                   
                            txtpwd.setProperty("text",Array(unamex.length+1).join("*"));
                        }
                });
    }
```

Get Editbox value using getProperty method

```
function Inputvalidation(control,callback)
    {
       var value_out = "";
       var editbox = document.getNativeElementById(control);            
        editbox.getProperty("text",
            function(property, value)
            {                   
                value_out=value;                 
            },
            function()
            {
                alert("getProperty error");
            });             
        setTimeout(function() { callback(value_out); }, 500);   
    }
```